# Highest Prime Number

Tags: ruby, loops, primes

I am trying to find the highest prime number for a given integer. I can get the first portion of the code to work, but the part where I check to see if the factors are prime doesn't work. I don't get any errors, but the output (puts) I receive is blank, so I'm thinking a nil is being outputted. What's wrong with my code?

```
def highestprime num

  i = 1
  counter = 0
  count = -1
  factors = []
  primes = []

  while (i < num/2) #checks for all factors of number
    i += 1
    if (num%i == 0)
      factors.push(i) #adds all factors to the end factors array
    end
  end

  while (counter < factors.length) #goes through whole array
    counter += 1
    count += 1
    while (i < factors[count]) #tests for particular index in array
      i += 1
      if (factors[count]%i == 0 and i != factors[count]) #if factor is divisible by a number, it is not prime, so break
        break
      elsif (factors[count]%i != 0 and i != factors[count]) #if it is not divisibe, then keep iterating
        next
      elsif (i == factors[count]) #if the end has been reached, then add to primes array
        primes.push i
      end
    end
  end
  puts primes.pop #print the biggest(last) prime number
end
```

Comment: You are thinking you are getting `nil`.  But you can check for that by using `.inspect` with your puts.  Just a note. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop pushes some of the values of `i` into `factors`; when that loop is done, `i` is at least as big as every value in `factors`.  The nested while loop, which is the only place anything can get pushed onto `primes`, only runs as long as `i` is less than some value in `factors`, which we just established never happens.

Comment: I just got Skeeted. I think I'm using that verb correctly.

Comment: Can't believe it was such a simple mistake. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for 27 or 500 or 1000, or other numbers hmmmm. It works for 21 and 22 and 26, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are reusing the iterator variable `i` between loops, but I do not see where you reset it back to `1`.

Maybe that?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [prime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) library. You can rewrite the entire thing in a few lines:

```
require 'prime'
def highestprime num
  Prime.reverse_each(num) { |p| return p }
end

puts highestprime(10)
```